# New empty project in Xcode 5, showing high memory usage in the debug navigator

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, memory-management, xcode5

I had created a new project with one class `MainViewController`, and that `viewController` containing just an `NSLog` statement in the `ViewDidLoad` method.

I noticed that when checking the memory and `CPU status`, that the memory reached `31.0 MB` after i ran the app on the simulator, and that was HUGE for an empty project with no resources !!!

You can notice that from the bellow screen shot for the `Xcode`:

[image: XCode Screen shot]

My project is for `iPad` only, and support `iOS 6` and above, and i used `Empty Application template`

Please Advice.

Comment: Still, the entire application framework has to be loaded into memory. Don't think 31.7 MB is a lot for a UI application.

Comment: I worked before with Xcode, and the maximum amount of memory i had ever seen was 20.0 MG for an application with 50 ViewController and more that 300 resource file !

Comment: I have noticed this jump in memory usage also, only seems to be with Xcode 5. I wouldn't worry about it though unless you are hitting memory warnings. Maybe the way in which the memory use calculation has changed in Xcode 5.

Comment: if memory growing over time you can check is zombie objects enabled in your app scheme

Comment: What are you comparing it to? How did you get your "20.0 MG[sic]" value?

Comment: @JefferyThomas i compare it with project which was created on Xcode 4, the memory is about 2 MB for empty project

Comment: How did you get the 2 MB number? The screenshot you showed is of a screen that didn't exist in Xcode 4.

Comment: When i run a previously created project on Xcode 5, i see the 2 MB

Comment: To clarify, When a project initially created in Xcode 4 is run on Xcode 5, you see 2 MB. Does the Xcode 4 project use storyboards? autolayout? Auto Linking? These are defaults on new Xcode 5 projects.

Comment: None, i used an empty project template